# how to select row om gridview by click?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How can i select row in gridview by clicking. But i want to add select id (from database such as primary id) in session. Listen please i dont want javascript Attribute method. Like that

```
session["selectedrow"] = gridview1.selectedrow[" which id? "]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Session["selectedrow"]= gridview1.SelectedDataKey.Value();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    protected void Unnamed1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["key"] = ((GridView)sender).SelectedDataKey.Value;
    }

   <asp:GridView ID="Unnamed1" runat="server" 
                onselectedindexchanged="Unnamed1_SelectedIndexChanged" ></asp:GridView>
```

Untested, but I don't see why this wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Setup the data key like this:

```
grdTestData.DataSource = GetDataTable();
grdTestData.DataKeyNames = new string[] { "Dataset_ID" };
grdTestData.DataBind();
```

Get the key (from a command button):

```
int iRow = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
Session["key"] = grdTestData.DataKeys[iRow]
```